# understand REGEX Meaning

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

There is a validation rule that I don´t fully understand. Can anyone please help me to understand the meaning of this REGEX?

```
NOT(REGEX( BillingCity , "^[\\p{Ll}\\p{Lu}\\p{Lt}\\p{Lo}\\p{Nd}\\p{Pc}\\p{Pi}\\p{Pf} .\\(\\)\\-\\+&@!'?/]+$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the **Explanation** section on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) very useful. You'll have to unescape your backslashes (replace (`\\` with `\`), and I think you are missing an escape on your final forward slash, so here's what I fed into their parser:

```
^[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Pi}\p{Pf} .\(\)\-\+&@!'?\/]+$
```

And here's their explanation:

> - `^` asserts position at start of the string
> - Match a single character present in the list below
>     `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Pi}\p{Pf} .\(\)\-\+&@!'?\/]+`
>
>   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   - `\p{Ll}` matches a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant
>   - `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant
>   - `\p{Lt}` matches a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized
>   - `\p{Lo}` matches a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase variants
>   - `\p{Nd}` matches a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts
>   - `\p{Pc}` matches a punctuation character such as an underscore that connects words
>   - `\p{Pi}` matches any kind of opening quote
>   - `\p{Pf}` matches any kind of closing quote
>   - `.` matches a single character in the list `.` (case sensitive)
>   - `\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
>   - `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)
>   - `\-` matches the character `-` literally (case sensitive)
>   - `\+` matches the character `+` literally (case sensitive)
>   - `&@!'?` matches a single character in the list `&@!'?` (case sensitive)
>   - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
> - `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

The `^[...]+$` formulation basically means you have a string entirely made up of whitelisted characters (everything replaced by `...`) in any order. Note that this does not mean your string must contain any particular character in the whitelist (for example, it doesn't have to contain `&` to be valid, nor a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in some way ---

- **\p{Ll}** or **\p{Lowercase_Letter}**: a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.
- **\p{Lu}** or **\p{Uppercase_Letter}**: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
- **\p{Lt}** or **\p{Titlecase_Letter}**: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized.
- **\p{Lo}** or **\p{Other_Letter}**: a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase variants.
- **\p{Nd}** or \p{Decimal_Digit_Number}: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.
- **\p{Pc}** or \p{Connector_Punctuation}: a punctuation character such as an underscore that connects words.
- **\p{Pi}** or \p{Initial_Punctuation}: any kind of opening quote.

  - **\p{Pf}** or \p{Final_Punctuation}: any kind of closing quote.

*For more Search "Unicode Categories in REGEX"*

Comment: Hi Nilesh, thx for that, do i get that right, that its state, when the city starts with a big Letter followed by small letters, this is accepted? But why would you put that in a field validation for City?  What about the rest of the code, after the Pf?